# Meaning of Counter + もの

Tags: grammar, particle-mono

> 何枚ものお札をつかんで窓口にいく

I found the above sentence in [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/78426/the-order-of-verbs-and-their-complement-adjunct). What is the meaning of もの here? Does it only come after counters, or can it be added to any noun? I've looked in several dictionaries, but cannot figure out which definition this もの comes under. Is this もの different from 物?

Comment: Isn't that particle も + particle の rather than もの?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56819/5010

Comment: @user3856370 thank you, I didn't realize